# Idealizer of one-sided ideal and endomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a ring and let $J$ be a right-sided ideal of $A$. We call the set $I_{A}(J)=\lbrace a \in A \mid aJ\subset J\rbrace$ the idealizer of $J$. The ring $E_{A}(J)=I_{A}(J) /J$ is called the eigenring of $J$. Prove that there exists an isomorphism of rings $E_{A}(J)\cong \operatorname{End}_{A}(A/J)$.

Comment: You have asked part A) already in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329611, and I gave an answer. So please: If you are satisfied with the anser: upvote and accept. If not: Please ask. Anyway, please continue the discussion on part A) at the original place.

Comment: Hi user66598: I switched "idealizator" to "idealzer" since it is more common: more people will recognize it, and it will show up in hits more often. The same goes for "autoring" which I can't seem to find on the internet. I replaced it with "eigenring" which I know was used by the likes of Kaplansky for that object.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious map for the second part is $a\mapsto a_l\in End_A(A/J)$ where $a_l$ is left multiplication by $a$ on the elements of $A/J$. Confirm that this is a well-defined ring homomorphism, and that its kernel is $J$. Conclude by applying the appropriate ring isomorphism theorem.

Bonus question:
Show that if you do the *left* idealizer for a left ideal $L$, that $E_A(L)^{op}\cong End_A(A/L)$, where the $R^{op}$ denotes the opposite ring of a ring $R$.